# ¿como almaceno los mensajes de mosquitto en una variable en python?

Tags: python, servidor, variables, mqtt

necesito hacer un programa con mosquitto y quiero almacenar los mensajes recibidos en una variable, probé haciendo una variable global dentro de on_message() (no se me ocurre otra forma de hacerlo) que guarde lo que se ponga en msg.payload, es algo como esto:

```py
def on_message(client, userdata, msg)
   global mensaje
   mensaje = str(msg.payload) 
   print(mensaje)

if mensaje == "b'hello world'":
   print("is working")
else:
   print("shiiit")
client.loop_forever()
```

me devuelve esto:

> > NameError: name 'mensaje' is not defined

pero si lo hago asi si funciona:

```py
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    global mensaje
    mensaje = str(msg.payload) 
    print(mensaje)
    if mensaje == "b'hello word'":
        print("it's working")
    else:
        print("shiiit")
```

desde ya: gracias

Answer (score 1):

el palabra reservada **global** hace referencia a una variable **global** que se utilizara dentro de la funcion por ende debe estar declarada en el scope global fuera de la funcion y a inicio del script.

```
mensaje = None  # global varible

def on_message(client, userdata, msg)
   global mensaje # indica que utilizara la varible global mensaje
   mensaje = str(msg.payload) 
   print(mensaje)

if mensaje == "b'hello world'":
   print("is working")
else:
   print("shiiit")
client.loop_forever()
```